# Property does not exist on type 'typeof' angular

Tags: angular, typescript

im trying to import a method to my component in angular.

But i get the following error:

```
Property 'alerta' does not exist on type 'typeof PasswordResetService'. any
```

And if you look the code everything is correct!

this is a component called password-reset.component.ts where i am calling that method

```
import { PasswordResetService } from './password-reset.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-password-reset',
  templateUrl: './password-reset.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./password-reset.component.css']
})
export class PasswordResetComponent implements OnInit {
  modalRef: BsModalRef; 
  constructor(private modalService: BsModalService) { }

  openAlertModal() {
    PasswordResetService.alerta("Título", "Mensaje").subscribe((answer) => {});
  }
```

The error is in the openAlertModal() method...

And if you take a look in the PasswordResetService everything is fine:

```
export class PasswordResetService {
  BsModalRef: BsModalRef;

  constructor(private BsModalService: BsModalService) { }

  public alerta(title: string, message: string) : Observable<string> {
    const initialState = {
        title,
        message,
    };
    this.BsModalRef = this.BsModalService.show(AlertModalComponent, { initialState });
  
    return new Observable<string>(this.getAlertaSubscriber());
  }
```

the method alerta() is there!

Anyone can help me with this?

Thanks!.

Comment: Please don't tag your IDE or code editor unless your question is specifically related to the editor itself.

Comment: Sorry about that..@MattDMo

Comment: You are not instantiating your class. So either create an instance of it (with new) or make your method static. Plus, why not use an actual Angular service for this and inject it like you do your modalService?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use service you should add it in the constructor
[docs](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4)

1. Register service in the module (`app.module.ts`)

```js
import { PasswordResetService } from './password-reset.service'; // Provide relavant path

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
     // Your Components
  ],
  providers: [
     // Your Password reset service
     PasswordResetService
  ]
})
```

2. Import `PasswordRestService` required in required component

```js
import { PasswordResetService } from './password-reset.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-password-reset',
    templateUrl: './password-reset.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./password-reset.component.css']
})
export class PasswordResetComponent implements OnInit {
    modalRef: BsModalRef; 
    constructor(
    private modalService: BsModalService,
    private passwordResetService: PasswordResetService
    ) { }

    openAlertModal() {
    this.passwordResetService.alerta("Título", "Mensaje").subscribe((answer) => {});
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1.) If PasswordResetService  is only a class, you must construct it first with **new** keyword.

2.) If its an injectable service (with @Injectable decorator), you must provide it in the constructor for dependency injection.

Thanks.